# Можно ли делать несколько join inner в одном запросе в PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

У меня три таблицы:

users

```
 user_id | username | password | email | role 
---------+----------+----------+-------+------
```

tasks

```
 code_task | user_id | name_task | description | state | category | create_time 
-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------
```

comments

```
 code_comment | code_task | body_comment | create_time | user_id 
--------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------
```

У меня есть запрос который делает соединение 2х таблиц tasks и comments по некоторым условиям, но мне надо чтобы в запрос включились данные еще и из третей таблицы users. И чтобы вывод у меня был не такой:

```
t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment
```

а (`u` псевдоним  `users`) такой:

```
u.username, t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment
```

Это мой старый запрос:

```
select t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment                        
from tasks as t 
inner join comments as c on t.code_task = c.code_task;
```

Как делается слияние более двух таблиц. Если можно не сильно закрученные варианты, так как я только начал с БД работать.

Comment: Можно делать сколь угодно много join inner в одном запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно использовать несколько `JOIN`, причём в вашем случае есть два варианта.

Вот этот запрос делает `JOIN` по `comments.user_id`:

```
select u.username, t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment                        
from tasks as t 
inner join comments as c on t.code_task = c.code_task
inner join users as u on c.user_id = u.user_id;
```

Этот - по `tasks.user_id`

```
select u.username, t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment                        
from tasks as t 
inner join comments as c on t.code_task = c.code_task
inner join users as u on t.user_id = u.user_id;
```